# git-clone local from git-only user to normal user (debian) - git-push takes ages/doesnt finish

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-remote

Lately I started my own git server which basicaly works fine for now.

The situation: 
On my server there are users like *git* and *user1*. Former is supposed to manage/store my git projects and have them accessible locally and remote. The latter is just a plain user I use to run telegram bots or something else.
Usually I create a bare git repository for user *git* like `project1.git` and in user *user1*'s directory there already are subdirectories like `project1` which I turn into a git system via `git init`.

Following instructions like [ProGit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) I link `project1` to `project1.git` as *user1* like this from `project1`'s directory:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@hostname:1234/pathToGituserDirectory/project1.git
```

After this I can `git add`, `git commit`, `git push` like it is supposed to be.

**However**, I would like to save the detour via `ssh` and clone the repo from user *git*'s `project1.git` locally.

As *user1* from `/pathToUser1Directory/`'s directory the following is working as well:

```
user1@hostname:~git clone /pathToGituserDirectory/project1.git. /pathToUser1Directory/project1-clone
Cloning into './project1-clone'...
done.
```

Problematic is the use of `git push` from *user1*'s newly cloned `project1-clone`.

```
user1@hostname:~/project1-clone$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 255 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
^C
user1@hostname:~/project1-clone$
```

As you can see, pushing added and committed files is not working quite well, since git is stuck  somewhere town the road and I have to intervene.
The added and committed files do not show up on other (remote) members accessing this repo.

Due to my (yet) limited understanding and short experience of git, my questions here are:

1. What is the best way to clone locally from user *git* (guessing
   via `ssh` is not necessary)
2. Where did I go wrong/how can I push
   files from locally cloned directories.

Hopefully someone can track my explanation and has some ideas. Thanks in advance.

PS: I could add user *user1* to the same group of user *git*, but there is no difference to what I described

PPS: user *git* is restricted to `git-shell`, but that's probably not the issue